# How to decompress .lz4?

Tags: compression, unzip

How to decompress .lz4 file under Windows? Is am not sure if it is supported in Windows. I tried to open the file using 7-zip but it could not open the file. How might I open and decompress this file?

Comment: This is a software recommendation question Erich is off-topic here.

Comment: Choose your tool here: http://lz4.github.io/lz4/

Comment: You can download pre-generated lz4 command line binary for windows at https://github.com/lz4/lz4/releases/latest, or compile it from source if you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

Below is how I did it:

I downloaded the latest version by the system architecture (64 or 32bit) from https://github.com/lz4/lz4/releases/tag/v1.9.2

Extracted the zip file.

1. Move to the extracted file in terminal (cmder, windows cmd or xshell).
2. Run the command

   ```
   lz4.exe C:\Users\rta\somefile.tar.lz4 C:\Users\rta\somefile.tar
   ```

   (this command will automatically decompress the file with lz4 extension).
   Output is:

   > C:\Users\rta : decoded 19962408960 bytes

Hope it answers the question.

**UPDATE**:
7-Zip ZS can be used to extract lz4 files and its just like 7zip. After installation, just right click the file and choose extract option.

The program can be downloaded from here https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip-zstd/releases